# importing interface module procedure from fortran into C

Tags: c, fortran, language-interoperability

How should I import a fortran `interface` into C using `extern`?

Suppose I have the following fortran module:

```
!swapper module
module swapper
   interface swap
      module procedure swap_r, swap_i, swap_c
   end interface
contains
    !subroutine implementations here:
    !swap_r takes two double precision as argument
    !swap_i takes two integers as argument
    !swap_c takes two characters as argument
end module swapper
```

Then can I just do in C, the following?

```
extern "C" void __swapper_MOD_swap(double*, double*)
extern "C" void __swapper_MOD_swap(int*, int*)
extern "C" void __swapper_MOD_swap(char*, char*)
```

Alternatively, if I promise to call `swap` with only double precision numbers, may I exclusively do this?

```
extern "C" void __swapper_MOD_swap(double*, double*)
```

Comment: Maybe this help you, http://docs.cray.com/books/S-2179-52/html-S-2179-52/ppgzmrwh.html.

Comment: There are no generics in C. But there are generics in C++. And there is no `extern "C"` in C. Are you actually using C++?

Comment: This has more information about 'INTERFACE': https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/f90_calls_c++/f90_calls_c++.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are actually using C++. But first lets answer for C or C-style C++:

No, you cannot do

```
extern "C" void __swapper_MOD_swap(double*, double*)
```

you cannot do it for three different types of arguments, you cannot do it even for a single type of arguments.

There actually should not be any `__swapper_MOD_swap` in the library in the first place.

What Fortran does is that it keeps an interface (which is just a description how to call something) for the three specific subroutines `swap_r, swap_i, swap_c` and lets you call it by name `swap`.

**But there is NO actual subroutine `swap` in the module!!!** Fortran will just let you call those three specifics under a different name, that's all.

There is no way how to call those functions from C like a generic. **C does not have this type of generics!** (It does have some functions which operate on any type using `void*`).

---

In C++ you can actually make generics which are specialized for different types and you can call the Fortran procedures as a generic, but you have to tell that to C++ yourself! You can make a template and manually specialize this template to call the appropriate `extern "C"` functions.

For an example see my header https://github.com/LadaF/PoisFFT/blob/master/src/poisfft.h where I make a C++ class which is linked to an `extern "C" struct` and some `extern "C"` functions which are however all implemented in Fortran.

---

Finally, DO NOT use the `__swapper_MOD_` symbols. Create some Fortran binding using `bind(C,name="some_name")` and call `some_name` through `extern "C"`, because different Fortran compilers DO use different name mangling schemes.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, including tips on best practices!