# Is it possible to call a Fortran interface from C++

Tags: c++, fortran

I have the following code that does not compile. Is it possible to call the Fortran interface as overloaded functions in C++, as I try below?

This is the Fortran code:

```
module functions
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_double, c_int
    implicit none

    interface increment bind(c, name="increment")
        module procedure increment_int, increment_double
    end interface

contains
    subroutine increment_int(a, b)
        integer(c_int), intent(inout) :: a
        integer(c_int), value :: b

        a = a + b
    end subroutine

    subroutine increment_double(a, b)
        real(c_double), intent(inout) :: a
        real(c_double), value :: b

        a = a + b
    end subroutine
end module functions
```

And this is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace
{
    extern "C" void increment(int&, int);
    extern "C" void increment(double&, double);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 6;
    const int b = 2;

    double c = 6.;
    const int d = 2.;

    increment(a, b);
    increment(c, d);

    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Overloading is usually implemented by name-mangling (this is an implementation detail and not a standard).  Declaring a function as `extern "C"` you are asking the C++ compiler to use the C ABI which does not name mangle.  Simple solution is to use 2 slightly different names for the function.  Also passing references across the C ABI is probably not going to work.

Comment: The two name version already works (including passing by reference), I was just curious if this could be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it cannot be avoided. But you can instantiate a template to call the two. Or just make a C++ generic wrapper to those two extern C functions. You definitely cannot make Fortran to export the interface. Interface is just a description how to call the two subroutines under some name internally in Fortran.

This question [importing interface module procedure from fortran into C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533633/importing-interface-module-procedure-from-fortran-into-c/44543373#44543373) is very similar. I even originally closed yours as a duplicate, but then I changed my mind because the attempted solution is slightly different.

But the principle is the same. Fortran generics and C++ generics are not compatible. And you have C between them which has no generics of similar type.

Note: As @RichardCritten suggest you also should not pass by reference in an `extern C` function. The compiler probably compiles it and implements as passing a pointer by value, but it is not guaranteed. Just pass a pointer. See [C++ by-reference argument and C linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906000/c-by-reference-argument-and-c-linkage) for more.